# T-SQL Query to count the occurrences of different conditions in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

DBMS: SQL Server 2008

I have a table with the below structure, which represents tender applications by a particular vendor in different companies and the status of their application. Decision R = Reject, A = Accept.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Company    | ApplicationDate | Decision | DecisionDate |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | ABC        | 15/03/2011      | A        | 17/04/2011   |
| 2  | ABC        | 23/05/2012      | R        | 01/03/2014   |
| 3  | XYZ        | 14/07/2012      | R        | 20/07/2012   |
| 4  | ABC        | 18/01/2013      | A        | 24/02/2013   |
| 5  | XYZ        | 12/08/2013      | R        | 11/09/2013   |
| 6  | ABC        | 30/09/2013      | R        | 14/10/2013   |
| 7  | ABC        | 08/01/2014      | A        | 08/06/2014   |
| 8  | ABC        | 10/05/2014      | A        | 19/05/2014   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Dates are in time-stamp format. Dates in the example table (dd/mm/yyyy) are for representation purpose only.

What I need to mine from this simple database is,

1. Number of tenders applied in the last 12 months - assuming 11/07/2014 as the current date.
2. Number of tenders rejected in the last 12 months.
3. Time in months since the last tender application.
4. Time in months since the last tender rejection.
5. Number of tenders applied in ABC in the last 12 months.
6. Number of tenders rejected in ABC in the last 12 months.
7. Time in months since the last tender application to ABC.
8. Time in months since the last tender rejection by ABC.

So based on the given table data, the statistics would be,

1. Four. (IDs 5, 6, 7 and 8 have application date with in 12 months of today)
2. Three (IDs 2, 5 and 6 have decision date with in 12 months and decision is R)
3. Two (10/05/2014 till today)
4. Four (ID 2's rejection was on 01/03/2014)
5. Three (IDs 6, 7 and 8)
6. Two (IDs 2 and 6)
7. Two (10/05/2014 till today)
8. Four (ID 2's rejection was on 01/03/2014)

Is there a way to get these stats using a single query on the table (possibly by using Sum with case)?

What I have so far is as below.

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, ApplicationDate, GETDATE()) <= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Total Tenders',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, DecisionDate, GETDATE()) <= 12 AND DECISION = R THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Total Rejects'
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, ApplicationDate, GETDATE()) <= 12 AND Company = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Total Tenders To ABC',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MM, DecisionDate, GETDATE()) <= 12 AND DECISION = R AND Company = 'ABC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Total Rejects By ABC'
FROM TenderTable;
```

That gives me 1, 2, 5 and 6 of the required stats.

Comment: Do you mind letting us know if this is a homework assignment?  If it is, we'd be happy to help point you in the right direction, but we do need to know so that you don't just get code with no explanations.

Comment: Those are all easy.  Use count(*) and datediff.  Use getdate() for today's date.  What have you tried?

Comment: Company of ID 5 is XYZ so point 6 should be 2?

Comment: @AHiggins, this is not a homework assignment. I am by profession a solution designer and has back ground in mainframe computing. However, one of the recent assignments need me to pull this stats. I am not proficient in T-SQL beyond the level of simple selects and joins.

Comment: @TI, My mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @Blam, added what I have. Might be inefficient, but that's what I got from Google searches :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WITH ROLLUP`

```
SET DATEFORMAT 'dmy'

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT, Company VARCHAR(3), ApplicationDate DATE, Decision CHAR(1), DecisionDate DATE)

INSERT INTO @tbl 
    (ID, Company, ApplicationDate, Decision, DecisionDate)
VALUES
    (1,'ABC','15/03/2011','A','17/04/2011'),
    (2,'ABC','23/05/2012','R','01/03/2014'),
    (3,'XYZ','14/07/2012','R','20/07/2012'),
    (4,'ABC','18/01/2013','A','24/02/2013'),
    (5,'XYZ','12/08/2013','R','11/09/2013'),
    (6,'ABC','30/09/2013','R','14/10/2013'),
    (7,'ABC','08/01/2014','A','08/06/2014'),
    (8,'ABC','10/05/2014','A','19/05/2014')

SELECT
    Company                          = CASE WHEN (GROUPING(Company) = 1) THEN 'ALL' ELSE ISNULL(Company, 'UNKNOWN') END,
    TendersApplied                   = SUM(CASE WHEN ApplicationDate >= DATEADD(M, -12, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) THEN 1 END),
    TendersRejected                  = SUM(CASE WHEN DecisionDate >= DATEADD(M, -12, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND Decision = 'R' THEN 1 END),
    MonthsSinceLastTenderApplication = DATEDIFF(M, MAX(ApplicationDate), GETDATE()),
    MonthsSinceLastTenderRejection   = DATEDIFF(M, MAX(CASE WHEN Decision = 'R' THEN DecisionDate END), GETDATE())
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY Company
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING GROUPING(Company) = 1
OR Company = 'ABC'
ORDER BY GROUPING(Company), Company
```

Which produces

```
Company TendersApplied TendersRejected MonthsSinceLastTenderApplication MonthsSinceLastTenderRejection
------- -------------- --------------- -------------------------------- ------------------------------
ABC     3              2               2                                4
ALL     4              3               2                                4
```

Edit by Questioner:
Modification to the query above satisfies the requirements.

```
SELECT
    TendersApplied                      = SUM(CASE WHEN ApplicationDate >= DATEADD(M, -12, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) THEN 1 END),
    TendersRejected                     = SUM(CASE WHEN DecisionDate >= DATEADD(M, -12, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND Decision = 'R' THEN 1 END),
    MonthsSinceLastTenderApplication    = DATEDIFF(M, MAX(ApplicationDate), GETDATE()),
    MonthsSinceLastTenderRejection      = DATEDIFF(M, MAX(CASE WHEN Decision = 'R' THEN DecisionDate END), GETDATE()),
    TendersAppliedABC                   = SUM(CASE WHEN Company = 'ABC' AND ApplicationDate >= DATEADD(M, -12, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) THEN 1 END),
    TendersRejectedABC                  = SUM(CASE WHEN Company = 'ABC' AND DecisionDate >= DATEADD(M, -12, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND Decision = 'R' THEN 1 END),
    MonthsSinceLastTenderApplicationABC = DATEDIFF(M, MAX(CASE WHEN Company = 'ABC' THEN ApplicationDate END), GETDATE()),
    MonthsSinceLastTenderRejectionABC   = DATEDIFF(M, MAX(CASE WHEN Company = 'ABC' AND Decision = 'R' THEN DecisionDate END), GETDATE())
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: Which question does that answer?

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to have the answer in a single row with 8 columns representing the stats.

Comment: @Jayachandran do you only ever want it for the one company or against all companies?

Comment: @Jayachandran once you get the results you need you can `PIVOT` them

Comment: At any given time only one company. So if I get the solution for ABC, I can use a variable to pass the company name.

Comment: @TI, I have made your query to work with a modification. Took the liberty to add the modification to your answer (kindly review and approve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overlooking an simple way that is not obvious if you've not seen it before.

For example, I have a Table Named StateCounty that has State and County data

```
select count(*) as TotalCounties
, (select count(*) from StateCounty where StateCode = 'AK') as AlaskaCounties
, (select count(*) from StateCounty where StateCode = 'TX') as TexasCounties
, (select count(*) from StateCounty where County = 'Marion') as CountiesNamedMarion
, (select count(*) from StateCounty where County = 'Washington') as CountiesNamedWashington
from StateCounty
```

Yields the output

```
TotalCounties AlaskaCounties TexasCounties CountiesNamedMarion CountiesNamedWashington
------------- -------------- ------------- ------------------- -----------------------
3131          17             254           17                  31
```

(1 row(s) affected)

I believe you can write the query you want yourself now.

Comment: Wouldn't this be less efficient than a single select statement with SUM(each case)?

Comment: Apart from not answering the question, this is a very inefficient query. It executes multiple queries over the same table. The same result could be achieved with a single query, eg `SELECT StateCode,County,Count(*) FROM SOMETABLE GROUP BY StateCode,County WITH CUBE)` to get all combinations

Comment: The point was illustration how you can force together queries that are  otherwise not easily grouped together. I did not answer the original question simply because user had shown no work trying to solve it before. Yes, it is clearly inneficient but it is an occasionally useful technique. I did not rollup or cube because I was illustrating a point. However, let me thank both of your for pointing that as since I clearly should have and did not not.